# How I can pull files from my Android Sony Xperia Z1 using ADB tool? P.S My phone is rooted

Tags: android, adb

I tried on my own but failed , when I looked around I didn’t find except tool called adbd insecure which make me can run this command 
“adb root”.

when I run this command I got no response on CMD and when I tried to use this program mentioned above on my phone I got an error.

when the desired action when I run the command "adb root" om my Windows 10 OS
is "adbd is already running as root" in CMD.
So far I can run "adb pull /data/data & put it everywhere on my PC".
Any help please.

Comment: Please post different steps that you are running in your terminal by order.

Comment: 1- Okay first of all I connect my phone and I enabled usb debugging already, I open my CMD and go to adb directory which commonly is  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools" .. 
2- Then I write adb root and got no response in cmd when I expect "adbd is already running as root"
3- I'm trying to get files from directory /data/data , pull them all & put them In my pc . when i run this command 
" adb pull /data/data "place to put in" "
i got 0 files pulled 
which i think permission problem. @Red M

Answer (score 0):

*Okay, so here are the steps that works for me.*
I'm a Linux user so you can later convert terminal commands to windows if necessary:
Since you mentioned that your device is already rooted:

1. adb devices--> Make sure your device is connected.
2. adb shell--> runs shell command on your device.
3. su --> gives you root access.
4. cd data/data --> (data/data/xyz) is apparently the file you want to pull).
5. pwd--> will display the path.
6. copy that path and save it somewhere.
7. use "exit" to get out from the shell.
8. Once you are back in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools, run adb pull (paste the path that you copied).
9. Now you should have your file. Hope that helps.

Comment: I made this steps Red but I got "/data/data 0 files pulled"..
okay let me say something when you run  "adb shell"  then  "su"  ...
you grant your self Super User Privileges but when you exit you returned automatically to regular user so you can't run the command  "adb pull /data/data" because this directory is protected by the kernel because it contains meta data.
So I was searching for a way make me do this...
so far thanks dude.

Comment: Are you sure the folder  /data/data contains any files? Also, if the answer is yes, check these files permissions. Probably having the file set to read only is stopping you from pulling that last.

Comment: yup I listed all files through entering in SU mode... Sorry but you know how to check permissions of specific files !?

Comment: inside the file, run "ls -l" it will display files permission. if it returns something like this dr--r--r-- that means you only have read access. chmod 644 will change it to -rw-r--r-- which will give you write access as well. There is plenty of resources on file permission online, so go ahead search for that. Also, your last question is not related to this open thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot , and sorry for that i'm just trying to accomplish this process.